# what are the commands to stop mosquitto broker which is already in use

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am running mosquitto by the 'make' command in linux ubuntu. What are the commands to stop mosquitto  broker which is already in use for it?
I am unable to stop it by using "sudo service stop mosquitto".
 And I want to know is there any command without using "kill" and terminating it, so please instruct me stop command for the mosquitto which is already in use.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to stop the broker is to kill it or if it's running in a terminal you can send it the same signal by pressing ctrl-c.

As long as you don't use `kill -9 [pid]` it will make sure it writes any required persistence data to the database before it exits.